# What does self-closing bra-ket mean in Robetson-Schrodinger Uncertainty Relation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, notation, anticommutator

I was reading:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg%27s_uncertainty_principle#Robertson–Schrödinger_uncertainty_relations

Where an inequality is presented:

$$ \sigma_A \sigma_B = | \frac{1}{2} \langle \lbrace \hat{A}, \hat{B} \rbrace \rangle - \langle{\hat{A}}\rangle  \langle \hat{B} \rangle | ^2 + | \frac{1}{2i} \langle [ \hat{A}, \hat{B} ] \rangle ^2  $$

I found the notation hard to understand:

$$ \langle \lbrace \hat{A}, \hat{B} \rbrace \rangle$$

Is bra-ket expression, but it contains a single expression inside$\lbrace \hat{A}, \hat{B} \rbrace $  (so it can't be a dot product). How do I interpret this? Similar problem arises here:

$$ \langle{\hat{A}}\rangle  \langle \hat{B} \rangle$$

where the $A, B$ are single-entities contained in a closed bra-ket expression.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Anticommutator.html

Comment: $\{\hat A,\hat B\}:= \hat A\hat B+\hat B\hat A$ is the anticommutator.

Comment: Ok so, $  \lbrace \hat{A}, \hat{B} \rbrace = \hat{A} \hat{B} + \hat{B} \hat{A} $. The bra-ket syntax (from my understanding) is of the form $ <vector>\rangle   | \langle   <vector> $ or $  \langle  <vector>  |  <vector>\rangle  $. The expression:  $ \hat{A} \hat{B} + \hat{B} \hat{A} $ I think is a vector (or a scalar which I'll accept as 1 dimensional vector), so to me $ \langle \hat{A} \hat{B} + \hat{B} \hat{A} \rangle$ is missing an argument

Comment: :), @ZeroTheHero Does my response in the comments makes sense? I don't understand why $\langle \lbrace \hat{A}, \hat{B} \rbrace \rangle $ is at all well defined  since, I'm under the impression whenever I see a $\langle, \rangle$ pair, there should be an inner or outer product occurring (with at least 2 arguments), but the expression written earlier has only 1 argument, the anticommutator

Comment: $\langle \{\hat A,\hat B\}\rangle$ is the average value of the product $\hat A\hat B+\hat B\hat A$.  $\hat A\hat B+\hat B\hat A$ is an operator constructed from the symmetric product of $\hat A$ and $\hat B$.

Comment: Related meta post: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10559/2451

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the expression has three different pieces. First, you have the operators which are represented here by hats, e.g. $\hat A$ and $\hat B$. Second, the curly brackets or braces represent the anti-commutator operator
$$\{\hat A, \hat B\}\equiv\hat A\hat B + \hat B\hat A.$$
The final piece is the "enclosed bra-ket" notation "$\langle\cdot\rangle$" you are asking about which simply represent the average or expectation value for whatever is enclosed in the braket. So $\langle \hat A\rangle$ is the expectation value for the operator $\hat A$.

Now the expectation value generally depends on what your state is, and in quantum mechanics (especially in the [Schrödinger picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_picture)), this information is contained in state vectors such as $|\psi\rangle$ and it's Hermitian dual $\langle\psi|$. So the expectation value of some operator $\hat A$, given that the state of your system is $|\psi\rangle$, is given by
$$\langle \hat A\rangle = \langle\psi|\hat A|\psi\rangle.$$
Note that in terms of notation, the left hand side looks like an abbreviated from of the right side. This is no accident, and is historically why the [Dirac notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation) was developed to look the way it does.

Answer (score 4):

The angled brackets here are *not* bra-kets. For any operator $\hat{O}$, the expression $\langle \hat{O}\rangle$ denotes the expectation value of the operator with respect to a state - here implicitly assumed to be arbitrary, but the same state for all such expressions occurring.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other good answers directly explaining the meaning, it would be constructive to see how it is derived:

The inequality is the generalized uncertainty principle, which is the most complete form of uncertainty principle.

Given *Hermitian* operators $A,B$, we define vectora $\left|q\right> \& \left|p\right>$ with an *arbitrary* wavefunction $\left|\phi \right>$ as:

$$\left|q\right>=(A-\left< A\right>)\left|\phi\right>
\ ;\ 
\left|p\right>=(B-\left< B\right>)\left|\phi\right>\tag{1}
$$

By Schwarz inequality:

$$\left<q|q\right>\left<p|p\right> \ge \left<q|p\right>\left<p|q\right>\tag{2}
$$

$$(\left<A\right>^2-\left<A^2\right>)(\left<B\right>^2-\left<B^2\right>)\ge \Re^2[\left<p|q\right>]+ \Im^2[\left<p|q\right>]\tag{3}
$$

After some work:

$$(\Delta A)^2(\Delta B)^2\ge [\frac{1}{2}(\left<p|q\right>+\left<q|p\right>)]^2+[\frac{1}{2i}(\left<p|q\right>-\left<q|p\right>)]^2\tag{4}
$$

$$(\Delta A)^2(\Delta B)^2\ge (\left<\phi\right|\frac{1}{2}[AB+BA]\left|\phi\right>+\left<A\right>\left<B\right>)^2+(\left<\phi\right|\frac{1}{2i}[AB-BA]\left|\phi\right>)^2\tag{5}
$$

Simplifying it, we have:

$$(\Delta A)^2(\Delta B)^2\ge (\left<\phi\right|\frac{1}{2}\{A^*,B^*\}\left|\phi\right>)^2+(\left<\phi\right|\frac{1}{2i}[A,B]\left|\phi\right>)^2\tag{6}
$$

Where $\{A,B\}$ is anticommutator: $AB+BA$ ; $A^*$ and $B^*$ are defined as $A-\left<A\right>$ and $B-\left<B\right>$ respectively. In general, the anticommutator part is too complicated to be useful.

As an inequality, the generalized uncertainty principle always suggests:

$$(\Delta A)^2(\Delta B)^2\ge (\left<\phi\right|\frac{1}{2}\{A^*,B^*\}\left|\phi\right>)^2+(\left<\phi\right|\frac{1}{2i}[A,B]\left|\phi\right>)^2 \ge (\left<\phi\right|\frac{1}{2i}[A,B]\left|\phi\right>)^2
$$

This is the usual uncertainty principle.